# TickWidth 0 for Categories (not in grouped category)

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to group categories in x axis in highchart. It is working fine. I want to hide ticks in Jan-Dec labels but show ticks in Q1-Q4 labels. If i use **tickwidth = 0** it removes ticks of both the  categories. I just want to show it in grouped category only.

**Note :** I am open for highcharts solution as well (not just R wrapper of highcharts)

```
library(purrr) # map function to make grouped categories argument
library(dplyr) # for select function 

df1 = data.frame("label"= c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'),
                 "label2" = c('Q1', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2',
                              'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4'),
                 "value" = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4)
)

categories_grouped <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(name = label2) %>% 
  do(categories = .$label) %>% 
  list_parse()

highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = categories_grouped,
           labels =  list(rotation = 0, style = list(color = '#3777ac', fontWeight = '400'),
                          groupedOptions = list(list(style = list(color = '#3777ac', fontWeight = '600'))))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df1, type = "column", hcaes(y = value),
                showInLegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible through API. Those lines are generated and displayed as one path. The only way to change this behavior is to change the core code. I found one place where I managed to do it (the code is bad, but it is just an example), but the function I edited is private and I don't see any way to edit it in Highcharte**r**.

See this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b3s4c7no/

```
var i = 0;
  // Pushes part of grid to path
  function addGridPart(path, d, width) {
    // Based on crispLine from HC (#65)
    if (i === 1 || i === 3 || i === 5 || i === 7 || i === 9) {
      if (d[0] === d[2]) {
        d[0] = d[2] = -9999;
      }
    } else {
      if (d[0] === d[2]) {
        d[0] = d[2] = mathRound(d[0]) - (width % 2 / 2);
      }
    }
    i++;

    if (d[1] === d[3]) {
      d[1] = d[3] = mathRound(d[1]) + (width % 2 / 2);
    }

    path.push(
      'M',
      d[0], d[1],
      'L',
      d[2], d[3]
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I am R user I need to see how to implement your suggested code in R. Is the code dynamic - I mean does it work for N number of categories in x axis (# categories can change)

Comment: No, sorry but it's not dynamic. I hardcoded removing some path lines coordinates (1, 3, 5, 7 and 9). Finding a proper way of doing this is time-consuming